# Resources for learning how 'advanced level' stuff in LaTeX

Tags: resources

I oftentimes only see dense resources (books/lengthy tutorials) about how to use LaTeX. They generally spend most of the time teaching how to make tables, use math mode, cite papers, and other basic things you would want to learn when first using LaTeX.

I would like to hear about more dense resources that teach more advanced topics, like for example
`making conditional formatting functions for tables` or `making a documentclass`.

Is there any single resources that can take an intermediate level LaTeX user to advanced level?

Comment: I'm sure we have some questions on site already for this but the latex companion book has some documentation on how to structure a document class, reading the latex sources (`texdoc source2e` ) covers most of the ground that you need.

Comment: You can download source2e.pdf from CTAN.

Comment: There are a lot of resources on overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles

Comment: @JohnKormylo you can, but chances are you have it already installed:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Huh, so it is.  In the base folder.